# Помогите доделать лайк

Tags: css3, html5

html:

```
<div class="like_1_desctop min"><img class="" src="img/like_1_desctop.png" alt=""> </div>
```

css:

```
. like_1_desctop:hover, . like_1_desctop:active{
     margin-top: -66px;
}
```

[image: справа лайк при наведение мышки, слева дефолтный, я сделал спрайтом лайк]

Нужно после клика по лайку оставлять цвет красный, а он только при наведение меняется

Comment: Добавьте код, который вы используете, иначе получается не "доделайте", а сделайте за меня.

Comment: Вешайте javascript-обработчик на событие onclick и в нём добавляйте элементу нужный css-класс

Comment: буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".like_1_desctop").click(function() { $(".like_1_desctop").css("margin-top","-66px"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Растровые картинки - не лучшее решение для иконок. Предложу решение с иконочным шрифтом **FontAwesome**

```css
.like {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like__input {
  display: none;
}

.like__heart:before {
  content: '\f08a';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: gray;
}

:checked+.like__heart:before {
  content: '\f004';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="like">
  <input type="checkbox" class="like__input">
  <span class="like__heart"></span>
</label>
```